# Stuck on merge/join/stack, more efficient way?

Tags: python, join, merge, stack

So I have the following DataFrames:

```
print(results)
           values
abc xy num       
a   x  1      NaN
       2      NaN
    y  1      NaN
       2      NaN
b   x  1      NaN
       2      NaN
    y  1      NaN
       2      NaN
c   x  1      NaN
       2      NaN
    y  1      NaN
       2      NaN

print(calc1)            print(calc2)           print(calc3)
        values                  values                 values
abc xy                  abc xy                 abc xy
a   x      400          b   x      100         c   x      800
    y      400              y      100             y      800
```

I would now like to join/merge/… calc1, calc2 and calc3 into results.

Merged gave me this:

```
>>> print(merge3.stack(dropna=False))
abc  xy  num          
a    x   1    values_y    400.0
              values_x      NaN
              values_y      NaN
         2    values_y    400.0
              values_x      NaN
              values_y      NaN
     y   1    values_y    400.0
              values_x      NaN
              values_y      NaN
         2    values_y    400.0
...               ...       ...
```

But I'd like to see this:

```
             values
abc xy num                           
a   x  1      400.0
       2      400.0
    y  1      400.0
       2      400.0
b   x  1      100.0
       2      100.0
    y  1      100.0
       2      100.0
c   x  1      800.0
       2      800.0
    y  1      800.0
       2      800.0
```

Currently I only received result doing this:

```
merge1 = results.merge(calc1, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
merge1.drop(['values_x'], axis=1, inplace=True)
merge2 = merge1.merge(calc2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
merge3 = merge2.merge(calc3, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
stack = pd.DataFrame(merge3.stack(dropna=False))
stack = stack.reset_index(level=3)
print(stack.iloc[:, 1:].dropna())
```

I can't help to think there must be a more efficient way to do this. Because now it's just three frames but I'll be doing this with hundreds of frames and then this way doesn't look like a very efficient way to get 'results'.

Or am I looking at it the wrong way and should I use different functions?

To give context to the big picture: I'll be performing several calculations on fractions of my dataset. There shouldn't be overlapping locations, meaning i.e. that position [a][x][1] can only come from one kind of calculation.
In my mind, the results DataFrame is a big empty table, and I'll be filling it with values along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed it this way:

```
for file_name in os.listdir(input_dir):
   if file_name.endswith(".csv"):  # Only process CSV files
       filepath = os.path.join(input_dir, file_name)
       df = pd.read_csv(filepath, dtype=str)
       df = constants_zeroes(df)
       can_mapping = pd.concat([can_mapping, df], ignore_index=True)
       can_mapping.reset_index(drop=True)
```

My fault was to focus on the indexes too early. Better to `pd.concat` a large file where the 'to-be' indexes remain columns. Eventually `pd.pivot_table` them.

For `pd.pivot_table` with strings make sure the agg argument is set to `aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x)`.